# C# coalesce operator Throws

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, null-coalescing-operator, null-coalescing

I have a class with a string property. I use the coalesce operator when reading from it as it might be null, but it still throws me an NullRefrenceExeption.

```
string name = user.Section.ParentSection.Name ?? string.Empty;
```

To be more specific, its the ".ParentSection" that's null so is it because it don't even have ".name" ? If that's the case should i test ".ParentSection" first with an if block?

I assume there are something about the Coalesce operator i dont understand, hope someone can shed some light on whats going wrong here.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Comment: As the answers imply, the null coalescing operator is not throwing here; it's the evaluation of its left operand that throws the exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> To be more specific, its the ".ParentSection" that's null so is it
>   because it don't even have ".name" ?

Yes.

> If that's the case should i test ".ParentSection" first with an if
>   block?

Yes.

Comment: Thats what i assumed, but i tough it might be an more elegant solution to it. Thanks :)

Comment: There is a more elegant solution called the Maybe Monad. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to check if `Section` and `ParentSection` are null. You could use an if-statement for this or write an extension method like this:

```
public static class MaybeMonad
{
    public static TOut With<TIn, TOut>(this TIn input, Func<TIn, TOut> evaluator)
        where TIn : class
        where TOut : class
    {
        if (input == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return evaluator(input);
        }
    }
}
```

You would use this method like so:

```
string name = user.With(u => u.Section)
                  .With(s => s.ParentSection)
                  .With(p => p.Name) ?? string.Empty;
```

I think it's a lot cleaner than an if-statement with a lot of `&&`.

Some further reading: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109026/Chained-null-checks-and-the-Maybe-monad

Answer (score 3):

You need to check if `user`, `user.Section`, or `user.Section.ParentSection` are null before you can use the null coalescing operator on a property of `user.Section.ParentSection`.

Answer (score 3):

Nested property access is not safe if any of the objects accessed are `null` this will throw a `NullReferenceException`. You will have to explicitly test for the outer objects to be not null.

E.g.:

```
string name = string.Empty;
if(user!=null && user.Section!=null && user.Section.ParentSection !=null)
   name = user.Section.ParentSection.Name ?? string.Empty;
```

In general I would try to avoid nested access to properties, you are violating the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). Some refactoring might make this unnecessary in the first place.

Comment: I would agree; `public String getParentSectionName()` would be a welcomed change I'm sure.

Answer (score 2):

The `??` operator checks if the left side is null and if so returns the right one, if not the left one.
In your case the left-side is the "Name" property in the object `user.Section.ParentSection` and this is null.

In those cases either think on what might be null or do something like this:

```
string name = user == null 
              || user.Section == null 
              || user.ParentSection == null 
              || user.Section.ParentSection.Name == null 
                 ? string.Empty 
                 : user.Section.ParentSection.Name;
```

(yeah it's ugly I know)

Answer (score 1):

Chances are `user` or `user.Section` or `user.Section.ParentSection` is a null value.

The `??` operator doesn't prevent checks like:

```
if (user != null && user.Section != null && user.Section.ParentSection != null){
```

Make sure that everything up to the string property is valid and exists, then you can use `??`.  You can't call `(null).Name`, no matter how many times you try.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to check if `Section` or `ParentSection` are null before you check `Name`

Answer (score 0):

It is probably best to do something like this:

```
if(user!=null && user.Section!=null && user.Section.ParentSection!=null)
{
     string name = user.Section.ParentSection.Name ?? string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The null coalescing operator takes a statement like:

```
a = b ?? c;
```

What this says is "evaluate b; if it has a non-null value then assign that to a. Otherwise assign the value of c to a".

However within *your* b you're using a user object which may be null that has a section object that may be null that has a parent section property that may be null that had a name property that may be null. If you wanted to check all of these (and typically you should) then you can do something like:

```
string name = string.Empty;  
if (user != null &&  
     user.Section != null &&  
     user.Section.ParentSection != null)  
{  
  name = user.Section.ParentSection.Name ?? string.Empty;  
}
```

As soon as the IF check fails it will not check further and therefore you don't get a NullReferenceException when you assume an object is present and then try to access one of its properties.